# VirtualBox - How to connect LAN computers to Windows XP Guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-bridge

I have software in a Windows XP Guest that acts as a server. I need to have my LAN computers connect to it. Is the best way to use a bridged connection? Is there another way?

I've tried setting up a bridged connection, and so far, it has an internet connection using br0, but the local computers on the LAN cannot access it.

Oh, and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64-bit, and VirtualBox 4.3.10.

Comment: When using a bridged connection your guest will get its own IP address. So not the same as your host. If this still doesn't work, check the guest's firewall.

Comment: Are your lan computers and your xp on the same network? check out their IP address first.Turn off your xp firewall too as Louise said.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I've tried setting up a bridged connection, and so far, it has an internet connection using ***`br0`***, but the local computers on the LAN cannot access it.

**`br0`**?!...It seems to me as though you have created a bridged connection in the host OS (Ubuntu), which is not the correct way.

Instead, go to VirtualBox, Select your Guest machine:

1. **Settings → Network**
2. Check **Enable Network Adapter**, Set attached to **Bridged Adapter**, Select the **Name** of your network interface which is connected to the same network of other clients (LAN machines).

   [image: bridged network adapter for virtual box]
3. Don't forget to configure (or just disable) **Windows Firewall** on the guest. If you don't do this, it won't respond to pings, for example.
4. Also, might need to hit 'Repair' on network connection on the VM (as I had to  after following the above).

Comment: Oh god, you're right. That's what the issue was. That fixed it. Made this waaay too hard on myself. Thanks!

Comment: The Bridged Adapter solution works very well: I have a Windows 10 as host and an Ubuntu 16.04 as guest with Virtualbox guest additions, and the windows host uses 192.168.25.69 whereas after configuring, the Virtualbox guest uses 192.168.25.70. I can thus connect to the latter from another computer with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by File -> Preference -> network -> add host only network

[image]

and add 2nd adapter on virtual device
settings -> network -> adapter2
click checkbox and select host only adapter
[image]